# How to create a waiting listener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listener

I have an android activity that calls and asynctask. In the activity I do some stuff and in the AT I retrieve information from a BBDD. When my activity starts a dialog progressDialog is shown.

I have a problem because I dismiss the progressDialog when activity stuff is finished, but sometimes the information from the DDBB is not retrieved yet.

What I want to do is to create a listener to check the value of two variables (main_stuff finished and AT_stuff finished).

How I should do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html): "A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface"

Comment: But I need an user interface. Because I want to show the retrieved information in a listview.

Comment: @MarcForn The service will always be active, it will not prevent you from using activity and show what ever you wish to the user. You can ask the service to perform a job and when he finished he will tell you, and you be able to inform the user about the result.